# IDA reset function name

Tags: rename, reset, ida

I'd like to set the name of my renamed functions back to their actual ones. I've been able to generate the name `sub_123456`, but setting it with `MakeName(addr, name)` aswell as with `MakeNameEx(addr, name, flags)` always fail due to the reserved prefix.

Has somebody been able to achieve this already or do I have to use a custom prefix?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried passing an empty name? That usually causes it to restore the default automatic name.

Comment: That solved the problem. I've tried that earlier but it got in conflict with another function in the script renaming the wrong address. Thank you!

Comment: @DCoder: You should make it an answer that could be accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass an empty name, IDA will restore the automatically generated name. This usually works with functions and data.